# How can I check for duplicates in multiple Google Sheets workbooks in the same directory?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that I use to enter data, and I want to check if the entered data is a duplicate in any of the other Google Sheets workbooks in the same directory. If the data is found in any other workbook, I want to highlight the duplicate cell to show that it's a duplicate.

I found a script online that works for checking duplicates in the same sheet, but I'm not sure how to modify it to check for duplicates in other workbooks in the same directory.

Here's the script I found:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var range = e.range;
var value = range.getValue();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var row = range.getRow() - 1;
var col = range.getColumn() - 1;

// loop through all cells in the sheet
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
  if (i == row && j == col) {
    continue; // skip the edited cell
  }
  if (data[i][j] == value) {
    // highlight the cell if a duplicate is found in the same sheet
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#ff0000"); //change the color code to whatever color you prefer
  }
  }
  }
  }
```

Any help on how to modify this script to check for duplicates in other workbooks in the same directory would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When a value is put into a cell on the active Spreadsheet, you want to set the background color of the cell of the duplicated value to `#ff0000`.
- As an additional function, you want to reflect this in all Spreadsheets in the same folder of the active Spreadsheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this sample, in order to use the Drive service (DriveApp) and `SpreadsheetApp.open`, please install the OnEdit trigger to function `installedOnEdit`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

When this script is run, please edit a cell. By this, the script is run by the installable OnEdit trigger.

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const { range, source } = e;
  const a1Notation = range.getA1Notation();
  const sheetName = source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  const ssId = source.getId();
  const value = range.getValue();

  // For active Spreadsheet.
  const sheckDuplicate = spreadsheet => {
    const ranges = spreadsheet.createTextFinder(value).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
    ranges.forEach(r => {
      if (r.getSheet().getSheetName() != sheetName || r.getA1Notation() != a1Notation) {
        r.setBackground("#ff0000");
      }
    });
  };
  sheckDuplicate(source);

  // For Spreadsheets except for active Spreadsheet in the same folder.
  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(ssId).getParents().next();
  const files = parentFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    if (file.getId() != ssId) {
      sheckDuplicate(SpreadsheetApp.open(file));
    }
  }
}
```

- In this script, when you put a value to a cell, the inputted cell value is searched from all Spreadsheets in the same folder of the active Spreadsheet. And, when the duplicated values are found, the background of the cells is changed to `#ff0000`. In order to search the values, in this sample, I used TextFinder.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the inputted value is searched from all sheets in each Spreadsheet. If you want to search it from the specific sheet, please modify `sheckDuplicate(source);` to `sheckDuplicate(source.getActiveSheet());` and `sheckDuplicate(SpreadsheetApp.open(file));` to `sheckDuplicate(SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("###sheetName###"));`.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createTextFinder(String))

### Added:

From your reply, I understood your expected result is as follows.

- From your reply, when you put a value to the active sheet, you want to search the inputted value from all sheets in the active Spreadsheet, and also, you want to search all sheets in all Spreadsheets under the same parent folder of the active Spreadsheet. When the inputted value is found from other sheets, you want to set the background color of the inputted cell and you don't want to change the background color of all other sheets.

In this case, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this case, also, the installable OnEdit trigger is used. So, please install it to `installedOnEdit`, and put a value in the cell.

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const { range, source } = e;
  const ssId = source.getId();
  const value = range.getDisplayValue();
  if (!value) return;

  // For active Spreadsheet.
  let check = source.createTextFinder(value).matchEntireCell(true).findAll().length > 1 ? true : false;

  // For Spreadsheets except for active Spreadsheet in the same folder.
  if (!check) {
    const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(ssId).getParents().next();
    const files = parentFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      const file = files.next();
      if (file.getId() != ssId) {
        check = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).createTextFinder(value).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
        if (check) break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (!check) return;
  range.setBackground("#ff0000");
}
```

Comment: the script is highlighting the values in the other sibling sheets in case of finding duplicate in current sheet but I  would like the script to highlight the duplicate values in the current sheet if found duplicate in any other workbook in the same directory or in the same file or sheet

Comment: Reflection of duplicate value must be only in the current sheet if found in the same sheet, same workbook or any other workbook.

Comment: @Basit Ali Thank you for replying. About `the script is highlighting the values in the other sibling sheets in case of finding duplicate in current sheet but I would like the script to highlight the duplicate values in the current sheet if found duplicate in any other workbook in the same directory or in the same file or sheet`, my sample script achieves this. How about this? If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: @Basit Ali About `Reflection of duplicate value must be only in the current sheet if found in the same sheet, same workbook or any other workbook.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand it. Can I ask you about the detail of your actual expected result? I would like to modify the sample script by correctly understanding it.

Comment: The script should check for duplicates not only within the active sheet but also in all other sheets in the same file or directory. When a duplicate is found, the script should highlight the cell containing the duplicate data in the current sheet. Additionally, the script should check for duplicates across all sheets in the same directory and highlight the cell containing the duplicate data in the current sheet.

Comment: @Basit Ali Thank you for replying. About `The script should check for duplicates not only within the active sheet but also in all other sheets in the same file or directory. When a duplicate is found, the script should highlight the cell containing the duplicate data in the current sheet. Additionally, the script should check for duplicates across all sheets in the same directory and highlight the cell containing the duplicate data in the current sheet.`, I think that my proposed script can achieve this. How about this?

Comment: your proposed script is highlighting the duplicate values in other sheets not in the current sheet where i am entering the data.

Comment: @Basit Ali Thank you for replying. About `your proposed script is highlighting the duplicate values in other sheets not in the current sheet where i am entering the data.`, I would like to confirm my understanding of your question. When you put a value to the active sheet, you want to search the inputted value from all sheets in the active Spreadsheet, and also, you want to search all sheets in all Spreadsheets under the same parent folder of the active Spreadsheet. And, you want to set the background color to all found cells. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: See I have a workbook named "A" in which I have 100 numbers starting from 1. 
now I have another workbook name "B" (Blank)  in which I want to enter some data and I want that if the entered data already exists in Workbook "A" or any other workbook in the same directory the entered data must be highlighted red in workbook "B" only.

Comment: If the value found in any other workbook the background color of entered value maybe changed only not the cells of other workbook.

Comment: @Basit Ali Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, when you put a value to the active sheet, you want to search the inputted value from all sheets in the active Spreadsheet, and also, you want to search all sheets in all Spreadsheets under the same parent folder of the active Spreadsheet. When the inputted value is found from other sheets, you want to set the background color of the inputted cell and you don't want to change the background color of all other sheets. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes absolutely correct now.

Comment: @Basit Ali Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize, again.

Comment: Thanks alot brother its working fine now.
can we just pop up the workbook names where is value is already exists while entering data in the desired cell?

Comment: @Basit Ali Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `can we just pop up the workbook names where is value is already exists while entering data in the desired cell?`, I think that it can be achieved. But, I think that it is required to major change my script.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand, by the way thanks a lot for your help and I really appreciate your efforts and the way you responded professionally.

Comment: @Basit Ali Thank you for replying. When you need a sample script, when you post a new question, I will support you.